Using Lang–Trotter to get bounds on averages of Fourier coefficients
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}$ and let $(a_n)$ be the sequence of Fourier coefficients for the weight two newform attached to $E$. The coefficients $a_p$ are the Frobenius traces given by
\begin{equation}
\# E(\mathbf{F}_p) = p + 1 - a_p.
\end{equation}
Where necessary, we assume that $E$ has CM.
The Hasse–Weil bound states that $|a_p| \leq 2\sqrt{p}$ and the Lang–Trotter conjecture states that for integers $r \in [-2\sqrt{p}, 2\sqrt{p}]$ we have
\begin{equation}
\# \{p \leq x \mid a_p = r\} \sim
c_{r, E} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log{x}}.
\end{equation}
Question: I would like to bound
\begin{equation}
\#\{n \leq x \mid a_n = r\}.
\end{equation}
Here are some useful facts about the sequence $(a_n)$.

The bound $|a_n| \leq \sigma_0(n)\sqrt{n}$ holds. This is a consequence of the Hasse–Weil bound.

$a_{nm} = a_na_m$ when $\gcd(n, m) = 1$.

$a_{p^{r + 1}} = a_pa_{p^r} - pa_{p^{r - 1}}$ for an integer $r \geq 2$ and a prime $p$ not dividing the conductor $N$ of $E$. If $p$ divides $N$ then $a_{p^r} = a_p^r$ for all positive integers $r$.


So far, I have been considering the case $n = p^k$. My idea is that the contributions from prime powers should be negligible. We can write
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{p^k \leq x \\ \\ a_{p^k} = r}} 1 =
\sum_{\substack{p \leq x \\ \\ a_p = r}} 1 +
\sum_{\substack{p \leq \sqrt{x} \\ \\ a_p^2 = r + p}} 1 +
\sum_{\substack{p \leq x^{1/3} \\ \\ 3 \leq k \leq \log(x)/\log(3) \\ \\ a_{p^k} = r}} 1.
\end{equation}
Here I use the fact that $a_{p^2} = a_p^2 - p$. The first sum is $O(\sqrt{x}/\log{x})$ by Lang–Trotter. For the third we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{p \leq x^{1/3} \\ \\ 3 \leq k \leq \log(x)/\log(3) \\ \\ a_{p^k} = r}} 1
\ll \sum_{3 \leq k \leq \log(x)/\log(3)} \sum_{p \leq x^{1/3}} \ll x^{1/3}\log{x}.
\end{equation}
What about the second sum? We can write something like
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{p \leq \sqrt{x} \\ \\ a_p^2 = r + p}} 1 \ll
\sum_{\substack{p \leq \sqrt{x} \\ \\ |a_p| \leq \sqrt{r + \sqrt{x}}}}
1.
\end{equation}
Maybe something like the CM analogue of Sato–Tate could be used here, but I haven't had the time to try it yet.
Motivation
I am interested in showing that the $L$-values $L(E/\mathbf{Q}, 1)$ or $L'(E/\mathbf{Q}, 1)$ are nonzero in certain cases. For example, for $L(E/\mathbf{Q}, 1)$ we can use the series
\begin{equation}
L(E/\mathbf{Q}, 1) =
2\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a_n}{n}\exp\bigg(-\frac{2\pi n}{\sqrt{N}}\bigg) 
\end{equation}
when the root number is one. I would like to bound the tails of these series to show that the $L$-value is nonzero. If the conductor is large than $|a_n| \leq \sigma_0(n)\sqrt{n}$ is not enough. Since I want to do actual computations, this does mean all the bounds need to be effective. I mention this motivation, because maybe we can prove better bounds using the fact that the $a_p$'s are equidistributed (Deuring).
